# substring uses in javascript

Tags: javascript, substring

```
// Displays 'illa' the last 4 characters var mystring = 'Mozilla'; 
var mystring4 = mystring.substring(mystring.length - 4); 
alert(mystring);
```

But how I will get string **"Mozi"** except last **3** character. when **"mystring"** length is **unknown**.

Comment: `mystring.length` can't be unknown if you're accessing `mystring`.

Comment: `var mystring = "This is an string"; alert(mystring.length);`

Answer (score 1):

To get the first four characters, you could simply use:

```js
var mystring = "Mozilla",
    myStringFirstFourCharacters = mystring.substring(0,4);

console.log(myStringFirstFourCharacters); // "Mozi"
```

`String.prototype.substring()` takes two arguments; the start index and the end index; although the end-index is optional and, if missing, will be simply return the whole of the string after the start-index.

However, unlike `String.prototype.substring()`, if you know you want to take a substring of length `4` characters, you could simply use `String.prototype.substr()`, which takes a start index and a string-length argument:

```js
var mystring = "Mozilla",
    myStringFirstFourCharacters = mystring.substr(0,4);

console.log(myStringFirstFourCharacters); // "Mozi"
```

Although it's worth noting that if you're accessing a variable – `mystring` in this instance – then the length property will be known.

References:

- [`String.prototype.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).
- [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `slice`:

```js
"Mozilla".slice(0, -3); // "Mozi"
```